# In RoR, how do I create TWO one to one relationship between two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In RoR3,

I have Users and Skills and each skill is created by a user. I wanted to record that, so I created a one to many relationship.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

However, each user also has many skills in the sense that, user "Bob" created skill "Kung Fu", user "Charlie" created skill "Karate" and user "Bob" both created and is able to do both "Kung Fu" and "Karate"

How should I represent this with ActiveRecord? Should I just create a new table "user_skills" which has_many :skills? and belong_to :user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different associations here. The first is a one-to-many association. An user can be the **creator** of any number of skills. The second one is a many-to-many association, an user can have many skills and a skill can have many users.

The first one is a simple `belongs_to <-> has_many` declaration. For the second one, you either need a `has_and_belongs_to_many` declaration in both models, and a related join table, or a dedicated join model, and a `has_many :through` declaration. Let's try the first one:

#### Method 1: HABTM

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_skills, :class_name => 'Skill', :inverse_of => :creator
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :created_skills
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This requires a join table called "skills_users" that has columns named `user_id` and `skill_id`

#### Method 2: Has many through (Join model)

The second one is similar, but adds a model that acts as the middleman. This has an added benefit that you can include additional columns in the join model, like for example a skill level.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_skills, :class_name => 'Skill', :inverse_of => :creator
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :skills, :through => :user_skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :created_skills
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :users, :through => :user_skills
end

class UserSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Having those two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
 end

 class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base  
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
 end
```

You would have to create an extra migration (without the model)

```
 rails generate migration CreateSkillsUsersJoin
```

which will give you

```
     class CreateSkillsUsersJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
         def self.up
            create_table :skills_users, id => false do |t|
                t.references "user"
                t.references "skill"
             end
             add_index :skills_users,["user_id","skill_id"]
         end
         def self.down
            drop_table :skills_users
         end
      end
```

The methods self.up and self.down you will have yo add them

Answer (score -1):

You'd be well served using a gem like [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)  which you'd be able to simply setup and use in your User model, something like:

`acts_as_taggable_on :skills`

Honestly, they've figured all this stuff out, as it's not as simple as what you're trying to do, OR I should rephrase that and say, what you are trying to do is overtly 'complex' and this gem allows you to just keep on, keeping on after it's set up.

Read the Readme.

Comment: Looks pretty good! I may have some later requirements which make me wary. What if I want to change the name of a tag from "karate" to "Japanese Karate"? I have to write a method to rename all tags, yes? Additionally, what if I want to have hierarchical tags where "karate" is a "martial art"?